# webtest takes only the first item from the datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, testing, visual-studio-2012

I have created `webtest` in vs2012

I want it to call a web-service with query string.

I want to assign new value to the query-string from a pool of values (aka data source)

I followed this tutorial

http://perftesting.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To:%20Use%20Data%20Binding%20in%20Load%20Tests%20in%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Team%20System

and have created a csv data source and attached it to the `id` query string parameter.

However all the generated requests use the first item in the data source only.

(I have created a for loop)

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

right click on the `loop` item
choose: `advance data cursors`